# Can SharePoint have different links depending on the location of the IP address for the computer?

Tags: email, geolocation

We are trying to set up a SharePoint site with a 'mailto' link that goes to the local IT support, however as the site is a global site we need to be able to enable users to pick their local IT Support.

Can SharePoint have mailto links that change based on the location of the IP address of the computer?

How does the office location attribute work? I am a novice trying to find the answer to advise our own SharePoint support on how to build this.

Comment: did you import your users from active directory? if yes, why don't use the office location attribute there?